# How to compare time using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a date value in a cell (let's say `A1`) and I want to check using VBA whether the time of that date is greater or smaller than a specific time (let's say 13 hrs). How can I do that? I tried:

```
if Cells(1,1)<TimeValue("13:00:00") then
'Something
end if
```

But that didn't work.

Also, if I want to get a time difference, for example I want to know the difference between 13:00:00 and 13:10:00 (which is 10 minutes), how can I do it?

Comment: Compare apple with apple :) Try TimeValue(Cells(1,1).Text)

Comment: To answer your follow up question read this article.  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/DATEDIF-function-25dba1a4-2812-480b-84dd-8b32a451b35c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if TimeValue(Cells(1, 1).Value) < TimeValue("13:00:00") then
```

should work.

Comment: That worked, but now I have another question. If I want to get a time difference, for example I want to know the difference between 13:00:00 and 13:10:00 (which is 10 minutes), how can I do it?

Comment: @t4xsyn Instead of "Value", "Text" to be used. As `TimeValue(Cells(1, 1).Value)` gives Run Time Error 13 : Type Mismatch

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub time()
If TimeValue(Cells(1, 1)) < TimeValue("1:00:00") Then
MsgBox ("Yes")
Else
MsgBox ("No")

End If


End Sub
```

Here's An Complete Example you cant compare an integer with a String an integer value can only be compared with the one with same data type i.e integer only Similary time value can be compared with timevalue(s) only.. Thanks

Comment: That worked, but now I have another question. If I want to get a time difference, for example I want to know the difference between 13:00:00 and 13:10:00 (which is 10 minutes), how can I do it?

Comment: that is easy @N.Pavon ,  I will suggest you to do some research before asking anything ,PS: its for your good

Comment: but if you still want it , i'll give you the solution for the same ,let me add another answer

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solutions using TimeValue() may encounter rounding errors which lead to incorrect comparisions in some cases, like when a 1E-17 difference in the serial values makes the 2 time values to be considered different.

It happens that the Time serial number is actually a Double, so it is a floating point data type, which naturally has imprecisions.

The best solution I found to avoid any rounding errors is to compare the format string, by formating it only with the portions of the date/time that are important to your application.
You can use this in conjunction to TimeValue to get correct comparisions

**Examples:**

```
'Answer to OP question:
if TimeValue(Cells(1, 1).Value) < TimeValue("13:00:00") and _
Format(cells(1,1), "hh:mm:ss") <> Format(TimeValue("13:00:00"),"hh:mm:ss") then
```

This way you guarantee that if the times are equal but have a tiny rounding difference, they will not be considered different.

**And some examples of  'Is equal to' comparisions between date/times:**

```
'Compare 2 date/time variables
Format(datetime1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss") = Format(datetime2,"dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss")

'Compare 2 date/time variables where seconds are not important
Format(datetime1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm") = Format(datetime2,"dd/mm/yy hh:mm")

'Compare a cell time to a constant time
Format(cells(1,1), "hh:mm") = Format(TimeValue("13:00:00"),"hh:mm")
Format(cells(1,1), "hh:mm") = Format(TimeSerial(13,0,0),"hh:mm")

'Compare a cell date to a constant date
Format(cells(1,1), "dd/mm/yyyy") = Format(DateSerial(2020,12,20), "dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code gets time values from range A1 and A2 and Shows Difference in A3.Just to give you a fair Idea how it works Thanks

```
Sub timegap()
Range("A1:A3").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss;@"

Cells(3, 1).Value = Cells(1, 2).Value - Cells(1, 1).Value
On Error GoTo here:

here:
Cells(3, 1).Value = Cells(2, 1).Value - Cells(1, 1).Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
debug.Print CDate("2000-01-01 23:59:59") > CDate("2000-01-02 00:00:01")
```

False

```
debug.Print CDate("2000-01-01 23:59:59") - CDate("2000-01-02 00:00:01")
```

-2.31481535593048E-05

```
debug.Print (CDate("2000-01-01 23:59:59") - CDate("2000-01-02 00:00:01")) * 24 * 60 * 60
```

-2.00000046752393