# Times comparison when formatted as strings in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have two columns, let's say `"A"` and `"B"`, that store a time value and are formatted as strings.

For example, `"A"` stores `'09:40'` and `"B"` stores `'10:00'` in the first row.

I need to compare the time value and check if `"B"` is greater than `"A"`.

I found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985267/how-to-compare-time-using-vba), but it assumes that cells are formatted as Date.

I also tried this:

```
   'colB' and 'colA' store the column letter, 'i' is an iterator over the rows
If Range(colB & i).Value2 = Range(colA & i).Value2 Then 
   'some code
End If
```

but it obviously doesn't work for this case because it can't compare the time values.

How can I do that?

Comment: When you say "formatted as strings" do you mean the Text format in Excel?

Comment: `Debug.Print TimeValue("10:00") > TimeValue("09:00")` perhaps?

Comment: @Vityata The cell type is "General",but I see the values aligned on the left, so I think they are in the Text format.

Answer (score 0):

I would usually put the values in Date format and let Excel care about it. Still, you can try to do the comparison yourself, with a custom function:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestMe()

    Dim firstVal As String: firstVal = "09:40"
    Dim secondVal As String: secondVal = "10:00"

    Debug.Print isFirstValBigger(firstVal, secondVal)
    Debug.Print isFirstValBigger(firstVal, secondVal, True)

End Sub

Public Function isFirstValBigger(firstVal As String, secondVal As String, _
                                Optional isSecondValBigger As Boolean = False) As Boolean

    Dim firstTime As Date
    Dim secondTime As Date

    firstTime = TimeSerial(Split(firstVal, ":")(0), Split(firstVal, ":")(1), 0)
    secondTime = TimeSerial(Split(secondVal, ":")(0), Split(secondVal, ":")(1), 0)

    If isSecondValBigger Then
        isFirstValBigger = CBool(secondTime > firstTime)
    Else
        isFirstValBigger = CBool(firstTime > secondTime)
    End If

End Function
```

`isFirstValBigger` returns boolean result, whether the first value is bigger. If you wanna change for the second value, then there is an optional variable - `isSecondValueBigger`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FormatTime()

    Dim Time1 As Date
    Dim Time2 As Date

    Time1 = Left(Range(colB & i).Value, 2) & ":" & Right(Range(colB & i).Value, 2)
    Time2 = Left(Range(colA & i).Value, 2) & ":" & Right(Range(colA & i).Value, 2)
    Format Time1, Format:="hh:mm"
    Format Time2, Format:="hh:mm"

    If Time1 < Time2 Then
    'Do what you want to do
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use VBA.  Excel can easily convert the values:

```
=TIMEVALUE(B1)>TIMEVALUE(A1)
```

or, using the double unary to force the conversion:

```
=--B1>--A1
```

or, using  any other math operation on the values:

```
=(B1-A1)>0
```

*Using the math operation method has an advantage in that it would insensitive to whether the values are strings or numbers*

And, in VBA, the conversion is also easily forced *(and also insensitive to the data type)*

```
Function timeDiff(A, B) As Boolean
    timeDiff = CDate(A) > CDate(B)
End Function
```

with the formula:

```
=timeDiff(B1,A1)
```